# Setting up MediatR with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, servicestack, mediatr

Probably I got it all wrong but here is the [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/tree/v5.1.0) registration at the [ServiceStacks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/v5.10.4) container configuration:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new HostConfig { DebugMode = true });

    var mediator = new Mediator(x => x.CreateInstance());
    container.Register<IMediator>(mediator);
    
    // This resolves
    var mediatorInstance = container.Resolve<IMediator>();
    container.Register(c => new MyService(mediatorInstance));
}
```

At a ServiceStack API service method if this is called

```
_mediator.Send(command);
```

then the error is returned:

> ```
>     "ErrorCode": "MemberAccessException",
>     "Message": "Cannot create an abstract class."
> ```

This line seems to be the cause:

```
var mediator = new Mediator(x => x.CreateInstance());
```

MediatR has extension libraries for different containers but not for ServcieStack (FunQ nor SimpleContainer).
So I do not know how to correctly set the MediatR.

Currently I am using ServiceStack v5.10.4 (latest: 5.12.0) and MediatR v5.1.0 (latest: 9.0.0) with .NET Framework 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

Since MediatR has an [example for ASP.NET Core's IOC](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#aspnet-core) I would stick to that, i.e:

> If you're using ASP.NET Core then you can skip the configuration and use MediatR's [MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) package which includes a IServiceCollection.AddMediatR(Assembly) extension method, allowing you to register all handlers and pre/post-processors in a given assembly.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddMvc();

  services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
}
```

ServiceStack's IOC will [automatically fallback](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore#net-core-container-adapter) resolve any dependencies in ASP.NET Core's IOC.

Comment: Can it be applied to self-hosted ServiceStack in a WPF app?

Comment: @JPollack ASP.NET Core's IOC is only available in an ASP.NET Core App. If you need to run on .NET Framework you would need to use [ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework](https://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx) which is limited to ASP.NET Core 2.1.

Comment: Good to know. So it is not possible to use the MediatR with the self-hosted ServiceStack on .NET Framework 4.5 in a WPF project?

Comment: @JPollack If it's a normal dependency you'd be able to Register and Resolve it like any other, I've never used it myself but from their [registration docs](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki) it looks likes it needs to rely on Assembly scanning features of IOC so you may need to use [one of their supported IOCs](https://docs.servicestack.net/ioc#use-another-ioc-container). Does it make sense to use MediatR in a message-based fx like ServiceStack? Do you know about the [Service Gateway](https://docs.servicestack.net/service-gateway).

Comment: No, I did not know about the Service Gateway. This is looking promising to de-couple the web services from the business logic using in-process messaging.

Comment: Isn't Service Gateway meant to call another web service internally? I need to attach a decoupled handler with business logic for each incoming web call. Thought to use a mediator pattern, service gateway could probably not be used like that.

Comment: @JPollack It's an abstraction to call internal or external services, e.g. internal APIs can be moved to remote hosts without code changes to existing APIs. I was just trying to understand the relevance of MediatR given SS Services are already effectively decoupled message in/out handlers. Like what's the benefit of the added abstraction to delegate the message into another handler? Esp. in a WPF Desktop App where I'd expect there to be less abstractions / unnecessary decoupling.

Comment: Currently the SS project has a dependency on the domain but I don't want that. I want to separate the API source code into its own code repository. Then I could reuse the source to provide the same API for two WPF applications with its of domain and business logic.